# Does ‘approximate' mean "approach" here?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

> Rousseau's strategy in both Emile and the Social Contract is to
>   develop artificial environments which enable us to approximate our
>   rational nature given our foreseeable human limitations.
>   — *Routledge philosophy guidebook to Rousseau and the social contract*, chhp. 1,  by Christopher Bertram

It might seem that this "approximate" means the same thing as "approach". But I think "approach" refers the subject only to an external object, whereas "approximate" can also mean the subject reaching a new state of itself. Am I right?

Comment: I think approximate in this context means "to measure".

Comment: Rousseau wants us to try to be rational rather than "measuring" rationality, so I think it is unlikely that Bertram had this meaning in mind here.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, it means, in the [Oxford Dictionaries definition:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/approximate?q=approximate)

> come close or be similar to something in quality, nature, or quantity

Answer (score 1):

He seems to use it in the sense of "attempt to bring out" but was looking for a more formal expression.